# Regex to take path until slash ("/") or end of string

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene

It is quite easy using lookarounds but they not supported in Lucene/Elasticsearch hence I have troubles to get `category/vegetables/<colour>` from:

```
category/vegetables/green
category/vegetables/green/avocado
category/vegetables/green/kiwi
category/vegetables/yellow
```

We can assume that `category/vegetables` is a static part - I just need to have a regexp that matches `category/vegetables/green` and `category/vegetables/yellow` but not others.

I was trying: `category\/vegetables\/.*?~(\/)` - take anything if it has not a backslash but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can't you use `category/vegetables/[^/]+`?

Comment: You are hero - seems to be working well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you wanted to use `.*?~(\/)` as an equivalent of `(?:(?!\/).)*?`, which is a very inefficient way to write a pattern like `[^\/]*?` (although `[^\/]` matches line breaks whereas `.` does not match line break chars, and, unfortunately, its behavior cannot be redefined in Lucene regex flavor).

Since you do not want to allow slashes in the part after `category/vegetables/`, you can simply use

```
category/vegetables/[^/]+
```

Note that Lucene regexes are automatically anchored, so this pattern will require the whole string to match.